# - CSS bootstrap, divs skip row how get neatly in a row dispite height difference -

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The problem occurred on other projects, but then I made all the divs the same size. I made a print screen of my problem.

[image]

As you can see the the third div is a little longer then the others (and yes I want to keep this). My css or bootstrap wants to skip a row.

html

```
<div ng-repeat="work in myWork" class="col-lg-3 col-md-3  col-xs-12" id="myWorkHolders">
```

css

```
#myWorkHolders{
    margin: 0px;
    display: inline-table;
    padding: 0px;
    border: solid 1px  #F4F4F4;
}
```

**Problem**

DIVS skip a row when the div above is not the same size as the others.

**Question**

what Css terms can I use so the divs will display under each other despite different sizes.

Comment: The ID attribute should be unique document-wide, it seems as though it's not in your case.

Comment: One way is to use a CSS clearfix every X cols like this.. http://codeply.com/go/Ffrwvu8aPE

Comment: If you use the CSS clearfix method, you have to be careful of the choice of columns. For example, putting the clearfix every 4 cols and using col-md-3 and col-sm-4: small screens are going to show 3 elements on the first row, 1 on the second row and then 3 on the third row. Something like col-md-3, col-sm-6, col-xs-12 would work better.

Comment: Using `display:inline-block` instead of `float` solves this quite easily … (but of course it means you have to overwrite the bootstrap formatting for the columns in that regard.)

Answer (score 2):

you can add an extra class with min-height to every div, just match the height of ur largest div and put that into css class.

```
<style>
.yourclass {

min-height:Xpx; //replace X with the height of your largest div.

}
</style>
```

and now just put this class into every div as:

```
<div class="col-md-3 yourclass">.col-md-3</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have run into this problem before; I'm curious what other people say. Not sure if this is the best solution, but what I did that worked for me was assign a `min-height` to those divs. the `min-height` you assign will depend on the height of your largest div.

so:

```
#myWorkHolders{
    margin: 0px;
    display: inline-table;
    padding: 0px;
    border: solid 1px  #F4F4F4;
  /* the exact height specified will have to be experimented with */
    min-height: 250px; 
}
```

Comment: This might conflict with the OP's spec: *"the third div is a little longer then the others (and yes I want to keep this)"*

Answer (score 0):

With bootstrap you need to use the row class to make sure the columns layout correctly no matter the height a particular column.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">.col-md-3</div>
  <div class="col-md-3">.col-md-3</div>
  <div class="col-md-3">.col-md-3</div>
  <div class="col-md-3">.col-md-3</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">.col-md-3</div>
  <div class="col-md-3">.col-md-3</div>
  <div class="col-md-3">.col-md-3</div>
  <div class="col-md-3">.col-md-3</div>
</div>
```

So when creating your loop you need to think about how to add in the row container after every fourth column.